# Unable to access web application by using ip address instead of localhost

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, port

I have created a web application using Eclipse.

While creating the project I have added Tomcat server. Then I ran my application and it worked.

Afterwards I installed Apache Tomcat service by executing the *service.bat* file through the command line and in the properties I have set startup type to automatic.

Now I can see the Tomcat in services tab but when I tried to access my web page by using  my IP address (http://192.168.x.x:8080/myroom/) I am unable to access it.

I am getting the following error:
***http:status:404 error - The requested resource is not available***

But when I stop the service in task manager, open Eclipse and run my application on server I'm able to access my web page.

Why am I unable to access my web page by starting the service in task manager and then by using IP address?

Comment: Could you please try to access http://localhost:8080/myroom ?

Comment: i have tried  to access localhost:8080/myroom/ but still iam getting the same error status:404 error - The requested resource is not available

Comment: You have to deploy your web application in tomcat server. You just have to copy your .war file to TOMCAT_HOME/webapps.

Comment: thanks  the problem is solved

Comment: did my comment work ?

Comment: @BHARATHRAJ, perhaps you could find some useful information on [Tomcat's documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse uses a different deployment directory.

You have to deploy your web application in Tomcat server. Just copy your .war file to TOMCAT_HOME/webapps.

Answer (score 0):

Your eclipse tomcat differs from standalone one in web app folder location
When running from eclipse it is .workspace/eclipse wstd core etc...  , when running from standalone usually it is somewhere on Tomcat folder

Comment: sorry i did'nt understand what you said as i am in beggining stage of creating web apps. can you please clearly explain the solution. i have only one tomcat installed on my computer.